# How to use oracle and jpa with a docker container?

Tags: java, oracle, docker, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring application which connects to a local database. The application works perfectly. When I try making a docker container, I get connection refused error and it won't connect to the database anymore.
This is the application.properties file:

```
server.port = 8010
# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=STUDENT
spring.datasource.password=STUDENT
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

This is how I run the docker container:

```
 docker run correctanadressserver:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The application starts and works, but it can't connect to the database.

Comment: Is your database in the same container? Or on the host machine? Another container?

Comment: It is on the host machine @SayanMalakshinov

Comment: so you need to use hostname of your host machine, if your container is not configured to run with host network: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ because your container has own ip address

Comment: just replace your `localhost` with `host.docker.internal` in `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe`, so it should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.docker.internal:1521/xe`

Comment: Ok, that worked, but now it says that timezone region not found and I can't acces any of the services

Comment: just specify correct timezone in your java call arguments or java properties

Comment: `java -Duser.timezone="`

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!